# Selenium IDE: How to detect menu item that has a dynamic ID

Tags: html, firefox, xpath, selenium, firebug

I am working with Selenium IDE to perform some test case recording and automation with Firefox. In my current test case, I need to click on a specific menu item. This menu item has its id dynamically generated so I cannot use that reliably to identify the menu item.

Here is an extract of the HTML code I am working with (trying to keep it short as it is fairly big):

```
<div class="mmenu-column last-child">
    <ul>
        <li id="liemx1271284633044.5005" class="submenu" menuuid="emx1271284633044.5005">
        <ul>
            <li id="liemx573969930099.0066" class="link" menuuid="emx573969930099.0066">
            <li id="liemx72897755668.1767" class="link" menuuid="emx72897755668.1767">
            <li id="liemx1355170643142.7795" class="link" menuuid="emx1355170643142.7795">
                <span class="icon">
                <span>Create Drawing Print...</span>
            </li>
            <li id="liemx1032692905053.1085" class="link" menuuid="emx1032692905053.1085">
        </ul>
        <li id="liemx625746376608.6172" class="submenu" menuuid="emx625746376608.6172">
        <ul>
        <li id="liemx696193179020.1482" class="submenu" menuuid="emx696193179020.1482">
        <ul>
    </ul>
</div>`
```

I'm trying to get the "Create Drawing Print..." element. I've used Firebug and got the following XPath:

```
html/body/div[20]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/ul[1]/li[3]/span[2]
```

And it works, but it is highly dependent on the width and height of the browser (changing the width or height cause the menu to collapse, thus changing the position of its composing menu items). I would need help in find a good way to get that particular menu item element (XPath or other) for use in my Selenium test case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try an XPath expression like this:

```
//span[text() = 'Create Drawing Print...']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this CSS Selector

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li[id*='liemx'] > span.icon + span")).Any Operations.

Please Let me know Is the above CSS is working or not.